# How to properly utilize UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, tint

I am new to `iOS` development and would like to know the proper way to implement a `UISegmentedControl`.

I've dragged out the segment, dropped it where I want, changed its tint color via the attributes in the sidebar, then changed the text of each segment. I then held control and dragged to `ViewController.m` to create an outlet. Here's that function:

```
- (IBAction)touchSegment:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    NSString *selectedSegmentTitle = [sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];

    if ([selectedSegmentTitle isEqualToString:@"2 cards"]) {
        NSLog(@"first tapped");
    }
    else if ([selectedSegmentTitle isEqualToString:@"3 cards"]) {
        NSLog(@"second tapped");
    }
}
```

This is intuitive, but it's not working properly. While the attributes in `XCode` all state I've set a custom tint color (selected the segment as a whole, then double clicked each individual one), only the left segment is tinted when launching the app - the border of the right is still the default blue. If in `iOS Simulator` I click the right segment then the color is changed to the correct set tint. I've also set which one should be selected by default in the sidebar, yet it doesn't show that in the storyboard. Not sure if I've done it right and these are minor bugs in `XCode` or if I've missed something or done it wrong in the first place.

Xcode storyboard:
[image]

iOS Simulator upon launch:
[image]

I'm running `Xcode 5.0.2` and the `iOS Simulator` v7.0.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is the way that the tint color works in iOS 7. You can customize your control further by using the function

[control setBackgroundImage: forState: barMetrics:]

you could call it like so -

[control setBackgroundImage:unselectedBackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[control setBackgroundImage:selectedBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: Hi there. I think something is definitely not working correctly. I've added some images for further clarification on the situation.

Comment: That's odd. I can't recreate that just using storyboard... Are you setting a border color somewhere in code?

I would try deleting that control and starting over. Some setting could have gotten messed up somewhere.

Comment: I've followed the exact same steps and the issues occurred again exactly as shown above. Are you using Xcode 5.0.2? Simply drag out a segment, hold control and drag to ViewController, type name and change from id to UISegmentedControl, click it and change the tint via sidebar, set the left one to selected, and add in the code in that function.

Comment: Take it in steps. Add the control without changing any of the settings, and run the app. After each setting change, run it again. That way you can pin down what is causing the weird change.

Comment: I'm not having trouble with a brand new app. Drag it out, change tint, run and it's all the same color as expected. But when I do that in my real app the right segment is the default blue until tap. Strange, since I'm not doing anything else with tint - not sure what the problem is.